# R memer - Error when adding text to memer PNG meme_text_bottom()

Tags: r, tidyverse

Hello this is my code from the memer R package:

```
library(memer)
library(tidyverse)

meme_get("OprahGiveaway") %>% 
  meme_text_bottom("EVERYONE GETS A %>%!!!", size = 36)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: rsession-arm64: NonconformingDrawingPrimitiveDefinition `text' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4405
```

help please!

It should come up with the image (meme) from the package with text added on top.

this is the package: https://github.com/sctyner/memer

Comment: I suspect there may be an unescaped special character in that text that `magick` doesn't like.  Does it work if you replace `"EVERYONE GETS A %>%!!!"` with `"Everyone gets a peanut"`?

Comment: Sadly that doesn't seem to be it.